# Refresh expired SAML Token for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, networking, network-drive

I am using Map Network Drive in Windows Explorer to add a Sharepoint folder. This link is supposed to be valid for the lifetime of the security token that Sharepoint returns. When the token expires, the only way to access the mapped drive is by re-logging on to Sharepoint.
Is there a way to refresh the token pre or post expiration that avoids this re-logon step, say through a console app that a user can run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try several approaches.

1. Configure expiration time to be long and create simple app or powershell script and run it with scheduler on predefined time period.
2. Modify Global.asax to neverending session.

Check this

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/08/09/setting-the-login-token-expiration-correctly-for-sharepoint-2010-saml-claims-users.aspx

http://blogs.southworks.net/fboerr/2011/04/15/sliding-sessions-in-sharepoint-2010/

http://jasear.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/sharepoint-2010-set-session-timout-on-a-fba-enabled-site/

Comment: Thanks, these are useful links indeed. I am veering towards handling this on the server by modifying the global.asax. Pardon my utter ignorance, but would this approach still work if Sharepoint happened to be on the cloud?

Comment: I've never had an experience with SharePoint running on the cloud, so here I can't help you. But I can give you an advise to ask this on sharepoint.stackexchange.com